# this code works properly in internet explorer but not in mozilla firefox. can someone help

Tags: javascript

can some one help me with this....
this code works properly in internet explorer
but not in mozilla firefox.

```
function initGantt() 
{
    var Gantt=null;     
        Gantt = new cTimeLine();
}

function cTimeLine()
{
    this.Units = "weeks";     //not considered as a function in mozilla firefox

}

function cTimeLine.prototype.initUnits(units)
{   
    this.Units = units;
        alert(this.Units);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you mean that `cTimeLine` is not considered as a function in Firefox? That is hard to believe...

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for creating a new function attached to the cTimeLime.prototype is like this:

```
cTimeLine.prototype.initUnits = function(units)
{   
    this.Units = units;
    alert(this.Units);
}
```